# NSTimeInterval 1 second difference with long value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimeinterval

Hi I am doing mathematical operations with NSTimeInterval(which is double type) with one long variable

```
NSTimeInterval  timeDifference =[endDateTime timeIntervalSinceDate:startDateTime];

  long duration= timeDifference-[dauseDuration longValue];
  NSString *eventDuration=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",duration];
  NSLog(@"Duration  :     %@",eventDuration);
```

where I am getting 1 second difference in result,can any one know's thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Likely a rounding issue; standard double-to-int conversion uses the floor value. Try rounding before the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

NSTimeInterval can hold only NSUInteger values.
When you subtract a 'long' from a 'integer' value, the result will always be a 'integer'.
The long will loose its precision.
Try using,

long duration= (long)timeDifference-[dauseDuration longValue];

(But not sure, if you can make up the 1 second difference).

Comment: thanks @karthik for reply I know solution just I wanted to know reason behind it, my assumption is due to rounding it is happening just wanted to verify.